# Setar tamanho do papel DOM PDF

Tags: php, dompdf

Estou precisando setar o tamanho do papel do `DOM PDF` para `80x550mm` preciso imprimir na minha impressora não fiscal `Elgin i9` estou motando o php assim:

```
   $documentTemplate = '
    <!doctype html> 
    <html> 
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.example.com/style.css">
    </head> 
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    '.$html.'
    </div>
    </body> 
    </html>';

    if ( get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
        $documentTemplate = stripslashes($documentTemplate);


    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($documentTemplate);
    $dompdf->set_paper("A4", "portrail");
    $dompdf->render();
```

O que devo fazer para mudar o tamanho da página, hoje esta `A4`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar o método `set_paper` (nas versões 0.6 ou anteriores) ou o método `setPaper` (nas versões 0.7 ou superior) informando o tamanho que deseja.
Na classe `Dompdf\Adapter\CPDF` tem todas as opções. Estou colocando elas logo abaixo:

```
    static $PAPER_SIZES = array(
    "4a0" => array(0, 0, 4767.87, 6740.79),
    "2a0" => array(0, 0, 3370.39, 4767.87),
    "a0" => array(0, 0, 2383.94, 3370.39),
    "a1" => array(0, 0, 1683.78, 2383.94),
    "a2" => array(0, 0, 1190.55, 1683.78),
    "a3" => array(0, 0, 841.89, 1190.55),
    "a4" => array(0, 0, 595.28, 841.89),
    "a5" => array(0, 0, 419.53, 595.28),
    "a6" => array(0, 0, 297.64, 419.53),
    "a7" => array(0, 0, 209.76, 297.64),
    "a8" => array(0, 0, 147.40, 209.76),
    "a9" => array(0, 0, 104.88, 147.40),
    "a10" => array(0, 0, 73.70, 104.88),
    "b0" => array(0, 0, 2834.65, 4008.19),
    "b1" => array(0, 0, 2004.09, 2834.65),
    "b2" => array(0, 0, 1417.32, 2004.09),
    "b3" => array(0, 0, 1000.63, 1417.32),
    "b4" => array(0, 0, 708.66, 1000.63),
    "b5" => array(0, 0, 498.90, 708.66),
    "b6" => array(0, 0, 354.33, 498.90),
    "b7" => array(0, 0, 249.45, 354.33),
    "b8" => array(0, 0, 175.75, 249.45),
    "b9" => array(0, 0, 124.72, 175.75),
    "b10" => array(0, 0, 87.87, 124.72),
    "c0" => array(0, 0, 2599.37, 3676.54),
    "c1" => array(0, 0, 1836.85, 2599.37),
    "c2" => array(0, 0, 1298.27, 1836.85),
    "c3" => array(0, 0, 918.43, 1298.27),
    "c4" => array(0, 0, 649.13, 918.43),
    "c5" => array(0, 0, 459.21, 649.13),
    "c6" => array(0, 0, 323.15, 459.21),
    "c7" => array(0, 0, 229.61, 323.15),
    "c8" => array(0, 0, 161.57, 229.61),
    "c9" => array(0, 0, 113.39, 161.57),
    "c10" => array(0, 0, 79.37, 113.39),
    "ra0" => array(0, 0, 2437.80, 3458.27),
    "ra1" => array(0, 0, 1729.13, 2437.80),
    "ra2" => array(0, 0, 1218.90, 1729.13),
    "ra3" => array(0, 0, 864.57, 1218.90),
    "ra4" => array(0, 0, 609.45, 864.57),
    "sra0" => array(0, 0, 2551.18, 3628.35),
    "sra1" => array(0, 0, 1814.17, 2551.18),
    "sra2" => array(0, 0, 1275.59, 1814.17),
    "sra3" => array(0, 0, 907.09, 1275.59),
    "sra4" => array(0, 0, 637.80, 907.09),
    "letter" => array(0, 0, 612.00, 792.00),
    "legal" => array(0, 0, 612.00, 1008.00),
    "ledger" => array(0, 0, 1224.00, 792.00),
    "tabloid" => array(0, 0, 792.00, 1224.00),
    "executive" => array(0, 0, 521.86, 756.00),
    "folio" => array(0, 0, 612.00, 936.00),
    "commercial #10 envelope" => array(0, 0, 684, 297),
    "catalog #10 1/2 envelope" => array(0, 0, 648, 864),
    "8.5x11" => array(0, 0, 612.00, 792.00),
    "8.5x14" => array(0, 0, 612.00, 1008.0),
    "11x17" => array(0, 0, 792.00, 1224.00),
);
```

Neste caso está em pixels, então eu não sei dizer qual a opção correta para selecionar, mas tenho certeza que alguma dessas deve te ajudar.

Comment: Teria como informar qual é o tamanho padrão do exemplos ? Por exemplo cm, px, mm para tentar fazer ?

Comment: Infelizmente eu desconheço as conversões de px para mm. Esse código que esta acima não é um exemplo, mas sim parte da documentação oficial.

Comment: É vi aqui, achei o tamanho porém não solucionou meu problema. Fiz outra pergunta e irei aceitar a sua porque pelo meu escopo ela foi respondida.
Esta aqui a outra http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/187553/problemas-com-layout-de-impress%c3%a3o

Answer (score 1):

Sei que o POST é antigo, mas para quem ainda está com dificuldade, basta fazer assim:

```php
// Onde 303 é a largura do papel e 2000 o comprimento.
$objetoDom->setPaper([0,0,303,2000]);
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).